# chktex: how to add an output format with newline

Tags: chktex

I am using `chktex` to check my latex files.
Now I want to define my own output format instead of choosing from given ones
with `-v<number>`.
This is via the option `-f`.
The problem is, that I cannot specify a newline.
For example

```
chktex -f%k%b%f(%l.%c)%n%b%m xxx.tex
```

writes all warnings or what so ever in a single line.
The format specifier resembles a bit C and `%b` is boundary.
The rest, `%k%f(%l.%c)%n%m` writes the Kind of message, the Filename,
Line and column in (...) followed by message Number and Message.

What is missing is a newline to put output for each message on a separate line.
I tried `\n` and variants first, but does not work.
I saw in `chktexrc` the specifications are given in a form `!n` signifying newline.

Unfortunately, my C programming skills are not sufficient
to answer my question myself from the source in `https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/chktex.git`,
but maybe someone is motivated to find out.

Comment: I managed with something like 
`chktex latexEngines -q -o latexEngines.clg -L -b0  $'-f%k%b%f(%l.%c)%n%b%m\n'
` in bash shell... hm.. but not really what I want.